# Extracting floats from lines with irregular surrounding text

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep, floating-point

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_start: 1.32515
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_end: 1.88188 | silence_duration: 0.556735
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_start: 2.99698
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_end: 3.42311 | silence_duration: 0.426122
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_start: 5.58311
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_end: 6.13984 | silence_duration: 0.556735
[silencedetect @ 0x7fa73cd000c0] silence_start: 7.6729
size=N/A time=00:00:09.12 bitrate=N/A speed= 675x
```

and I would like to extract the values that follow the "silence_start:" and "silence_end:" bits (i.e. the values 1.32515, 1.88188,..., 7.6729) as well as the value that follows the "time=" (i.e. 00:00:09.12).

I'm new to grep/sed/awk and trying to learn how to use one of them to do this but after struggling it's just not happening. I've tried various ideas and looked online, but success continues to escape me. A Python suggestion/solution would also be great. Tried that as well and it's a mess.

Could anyone please kindly offer any help with this? I'd greatly appreciate it...thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you show your struggles so far? Someone may be able to help fix them...

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep and [Perl regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '(silence_start: |silence_end: |time=)\K[0-9:.]+' file
```

Output:

```
1.32515
1.88188
2.99698
3.42311
5.58311
6.13984
7.6729
00:00:09.12
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu **awk** solution:

```
 cat tst.awk
 {  s=gensub(/.*(time=|silence_(start|end): )([0-9.:]+).*/, "\\3", "g");
    print s
 }
```

explanation regex:

```
.*                              # anything
(                               # group 1 start
  time=                         # matching string "time="
  |                             # OR
  silence_(start|end):          # matching string "silence_start: "
                                # or "silence_end: " 
)                               # group 1 end
(                               # group 3 start
  [0-9.:]+                      # combination of number, "." and ":"
)                               # group 3 end
.*                              # anything
```

You can use this as:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
1.32515
1.88188
2.99698
3.42311
5.58311
6.13984
7.6729
00:00:09.12
```

or as oneliner:

```
 awk '{s=gensub(/.*(time=|silence_(start|end): )([0-9.:]+).*/, "\\3", "g"); print s}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**sed** solution:

```
sed -E 's/.*(silence_(start|end): |time=)([^[:space:]]+).*/\3/' file
```

- `\3` - points to the 3rd parenthesized captured `(...)` group

The output:

```
1.32515
1.88188
2.99698
3.42311
5.58311
6.13984
7.6729
00:00:09.12
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have name to value mappings in your input a solution that creates an array of those mappings first (e.g. `n2v[]` below) and then lets you access the values by their names usually proves to be the most robust and easiest to enhance in future when your requirements change:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[ =]" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sub(/:$/,"",$i)
        n2v[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    prt("silence_start")
    prt("silence_end")
    prt("time")
}
function prt(name) {
    if (name in n2v) {
        print name, n2v[name]
        delete n2v[name]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
silence_start 1.32515
silence_end 1.88188
silence_start 2.99698
silence_end 3.42311
silence_start 5.58311
silence_end 6.13984
silence_start 7.6729
time 00:00:09.12
```

Remove `name,` from the print line if you ONLY want the values output.

For example if you wanted to print the silence start, end, and duration triples on 1 line each, it'd be trivial:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[ =]" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sub(/:$/,"",$i)
        n2v[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
}
"silence_end" in n2v {
    print n2v["silence_start"], n2v["silence_end"], n2v["silence_duration"]
    delete n2v
}
END { print n2v["time"] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1.32515 1.88188 0.556735
2.99698 3.42311 0.426122
5.58311 6.13984 0.556735
00:00:09.12
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX installation (or Windows if you have an awk for Windows).